# Calling 2 functions in java repaint() and then func1() but func1() is being called first and then repaint(). why?

Tags: java, repaint

I am using 2 classes `class1` and `class2`, in java, both being in different packages. `class2` has a `paintComponent()` and a `test()` defined in it. I am calling these methods from class1 in the following sequence..

```
objclass2.repaint()
objclass2.test()
objclass2.repaint()
```

but I dont know why `test()` is executed first. `repaint()` is executed next.. plus the second `repaint()` is not executed as all.. Why is it so??

**EDIT**

```
for(int i=0;i<170;i++)
    {
        az.animate(i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(160);
        } catch (InterruptedException ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

animate method():-

```
pd.setCurrentAltitudeScaleValue(val);
azl.update();
azl.repaint();
```

and in the `azl.paintComponent()` I am drawing a few things.. The animate method is being called every time the `for` loop executes but it doesnot call the `repaint()` again.. means `repaint` method is called only once though the `animate()` is called again and again..

Comment: Place [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) code. This will help to get the answer faster.

Comment: As an interesting execerise, you could go through the "coalesce events" code as @trashgod mentions to find out the precise circumstances under which these events are coalesced. But I think it's kind of besides the point. These events can be coalesced under whatever circumstances, which aren't necessarily fixed from JDK version to JDK version, so the answer is to not rely on this precise behaviour that is not fixed and not under your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean that paintComponent() is exhibiting the behaviour you mention. Bear in mind that:

- when you call repaint(), that basically flags the component to say "this component needs re-painting at the next convenient moment from the event thread"
- calls to paintComponent() can be coalesced.

If the design of your program really relies on the order in which paintCompoent() is called, then I would suggest you choose a different design.

Comment: but what about the second repaint not being called at all.. even if I call the repaint() in a for loop which runs some hundred times with a sleep() between every call, even then only one of the repaint() is being called.. Why is it so??

Comment: @coder: See [`coalesceEvents()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#coalesceEvents%28java.awt.AWTEvent,%20java.awt.AWTEvent%29).